# How to get the tagname of child in selenium as string and perform action based on tagname type

Tags: selenium

```
inputText1= browserFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-table-bordered']//tbody/tr));
WebElement childAttr = inputText1.findElement(By.xpath("./child::"));
if (childAttr.getTagName()=="input")  // if the type of the field is input textbox,,then below will happen
{
inputText1.findElement(By.xpath("./input"));
SendKeys(inputText1,"TypeInput");
}
else if (childAttr.getTagName()=="./select"));  // if its is dropdown
{
inputText1.findElement(By.xpath("./select"));
SelectListValueName(inputText1,"TypeSelect");
}
```

Exception is thrown at "child::" is not a proper string. remove "./" and tried. Is it the correct way of approach

Comment: You need to specify a tag of the child. If you want _any_ child, you can use `child::*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you simple use <kbd>getTagName()</kbd> method to get the element tag.

```
row= browserFactory.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-table-bordered']//tbody/tr]"));
WebElement targetEle = inputText1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[local-name()='input' or local-name()='select']");
// check if the row have either input/listbox
if (targetEle.getTagName().equals('input'))  // if the type of the field is input textbox,,then below will happen
{
    SendKeys(targetEle,"TypeInput");
}
else if (targetEle.getTagName().equals("select"));  // if its is dropdown
{
    SelectListValueName(targetEle,"TypeSelect");
}
```

Comment: Tried that . It gave me "tr" , the current tagname. HOw can I get the child tagname plz. There are set of few input boxes, few are dropdowns and few are textbox inputs.

Comment: Yes. With in tr there is either "input" type or "select" type. I want to get that tagnameType type in to a string.

Comment: Sure.. doing tht

Comment: now the TargetEle type is Input. But it is not going in to the fin condition of input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211566/discussion-between-supputuri-and-inspiron).